# How to prevent end-date shift when changing start-date in Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar

Any time I change the starting date of an event for example by extending it with an extra day (e.g. from 5th of July to 4th of July) the ending date gets shifted accordingly (e.g. 10th of July to 9th of July), assuming that the event itself has a fixed lenght instead of assuming that the timespan changes. The same happens with ending date changes.

I think it is reasonable to have this behaviour for time changes of events, assuming that a standard meeting is 2 hours for Google, but the same does not hold for multiple-day-events for me. Is there any way to change the behaviour for such events?

Comment: Not built in to Google Calendar, no. For what it's worth, this is the way I've always seen computer-based calendars work, not just Google Calendar.